# Jquery: Move the focus of an <a> tag from a single word to the entire text <div>

Tags: jquery, html, dom, string

Would appreciate any pointers regarding which function to use for this:

Say I have something like this:

```
<div class="myTweet">Check out this awesome link <a href="http://bit.ly/uglylookinglink>http://bit.ly/uglylookinglink</a></div>
```

Which reads:

Check out my awesome link http://bit.ly/uglylookinglink

All I want to do is move the  tag to the front of the containing div so that the whole sentence becomes the link, and remove the horrible http://bitl.y link that comes with it.

So it would look like this afterwards:

```
<div class="myTweet"><a href="http://bit.ly/uglylookinglink>Check out this awesome link </a></div>
```

Which will then read:

Check out my awesome link

It's probably really easy but i cant find the right way to go.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) and the `<a>` itself to do so, like this:

```
​$(".myTweet a")​​​​​​​​​​​​​.each(function() {
  $(this).empty().parent().wrapInner(this);
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ybbuQ/), this takes the link, removes it original contents via [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), then wraps the `<div>`'s text using the anchor element itself.